# Xubuntu installation monitor problem

Tags: boot, xubuntu, resolution, monitor

I have an old PC (Intel Celeron 1.7Ghz, 512+128Mb RAM, 40GB HDD) running Windows XP and I am trying to install XUbuntu 14.04 using UNetbootin booting the `.iso` image from the HDD. It boots well and the Xubuntu loading bar appears.

Next, the screen splashes twice but my monitor gives an error (screen resolution error) and nothing appear after that!

Any ideas?

update: I connected my TV instead of my old 15" monitor & it worked well.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Could you help us help you  by providing a link to a picture of what you see on your screen?

Comment: Standard question: Have you verified the hashes of the iso file you downloaded? And would you be able to burn a DVD or at least use a bootable USB stick to try the installation, if we can not find a proper solution?

Comment: @ByteCommander It works on the TV, so unlikely to be a hashing problem.

Comment: @Fabby He did not have mentioned the TV when I asked for the verified hashes...

Answer (score 0):

If Ubuntu loads well on your TV, but not on the monitor, hook up both together and configure the monitor while looking at the TV using the system settings - screen display.  Once done configuring, shut down the computer, remove the TV and boot the computer again.

This will then give you a working system on the monitor.